# Crash when launching Ark: Survival Evolved

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

Whenever I launch the game on any of the Steam launch settings for Ark: Survival Evolved, I get this error message. [image: The Error]

My rig should be fine, it is:

Graphics Card: Zotac GeForce GTX 970 Amp! Extreme Core Edition

Processor: Intel i7-3820 8 core

RAM: 16 GB

Comment: Have you verified local files?

Comment: @sommerjj They just released an update, I'll see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug and addressed/fixed in the recent patch.